# Prevent Windows 10 control html5 video playback

Tags: windows, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm working on site that uses video that should not be stopped by user.

But when video is playing I can change system volume and I see system overlay in top-left screen corner where I can click 'pause' and pause video.

Are there any ways to prevent such behavior? I mean via html / js etc.

System: Windows 10

Browser: Chrome + Chrome-based

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control this. Browsers and most operating systems give users the ability to stop media from playing. In the case of Windows 10, it's the OS that allows users to control the media, and there's zero you can do from the JavaScript layer to change that.

Comment: I can. I found a simple solution: call video 'play()' method in case 'pause' event occured. But it looks strange that system overlay button does not change from 'pause' state. I hope there is a way to tell system to 'skip' such videos from outer control.